# Load formulasR1C1 of a formula that contains ranges in Excel Online

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I need to get `formulasR1C1` of cells in an add-in. It does not seem that `Excel Online` gets right `formulasR1C1` when the argument of the formula contains ranges (rather than single cells).

For example, let's enter formulasR1C1 `=SUM(RC[2]:RC[3])` (ie, `=SUM(E5:F5)` in A1 style) in Cell `C5`. Here is a screenshot under `Excel 2016 for Windows` in R1C1 style:

[image]

Then, we use the following code to read its `formulas` and `formulasR1C1`.

```
function test () {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var c5 = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("C5");
        c5.load(["formulas", "formulasR1C1"]);
        return ctx.sync().then(function () {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
                "C5.formulas: " + c5.formulas[0][0] + "<br>" +
                "C5.formulasR1C1: " + c5.formulasR1C1[0][0];    
        });
    });
}
```

In `Excel 2016 for Windows`, it returns correctly:

[image]

However, in `Excel Online`, the returned `formulasR1C1` is not correct:

[image]

Note that, for a formula that contains ONLY single cells (eg, `=RC[2]+RC[3]`), formulasR1C1 are correctly loaded in Excel Online.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely sounds like a bug. Let me redirect it to the team.  Stay tuned.